# Quantifying the "curviness" of a spline

Tags: optimization, spline

I'm developing an optimization problem that requires me to quantify the "curviness" of a spline. The spline is defined in a software library, and the only input to generate a spline with this library is a set of control points. The spline is then parametrized in the range [0, 1], and the software library allows me to then calculate the position, tangent, and normal at any point t along the range.

Given this, how might I be able to quantify how curvy the spline is between two adjacent control points (e.g., if the spline through the two control points is simply a straight line, then the metric should give a value of 0, but if it is curved, anything > 0).

Comment: Integrating the curvature seems like a good starting place https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#:~:text=Intuitively%2C%20the%20curvature%20describes%20for,larger%20this%20rate%20of%20change.

Comment: (probably the absolute value of the curvature)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Esequin/PAPERS/2009_CAD_Levien_Sequin.pdf) might be a good place to start. It discusses curves that minimize "energy" and variation of curvature, which are both plausible measures of curviness. If you like Levien's approach, you can find a lot more detail in [his Ph.D. thesis](https://levien.com/phd/thesis.pdf).